# How to bind meteor to ipv6

Tags: meteor, ipv6

I'm using MeteorJs 1.4.3. It seems to run command bind http server to ipv4.

How I can start meteor on ipv6 80 port? Which argument or option should I pass to CLI?

Comment: I think you can set an environment var `BIND_IP=<ip>`.  If you are *nix (Unix, Linux, OS X) you can do something like `BIND_IP=<ipv6> meteor run`.

Comment: @CodeChimp yeah, BIND_IP=:: worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set environment variable `BIND_IP` to `::`.